# Location of Wordpress installation in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: wordpress, sftp, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to use Google Cloud Platform to launch a Wordpress. However, I need to tweak some of the codes in Wordpress.

I tried using the launcher to create an instance with both Wordpress and Bitnami. However, when I login using SFTP in a attempt to modify some of the codes, I can't find the folders for the wordpress installation. Where are they? In fact, there is nothing in the remote site. I can only see those folders and files in the attached image [image].

My questions are: 
1. If I have to tweak the wordpress code, is it a good idea to use the launcher?
2. Is it correct/possible to use ftp to gain access to the codes?

Comment: in 2021, now my files are at /bitnami/wordpress location under the bitnami user. And Yeah, bitnami is changing the location with their updates. Anyone who have installed wordpress on gcp using bitnami, this might help.

Answer (score 8):

When you access the server using FTP you are going to the Home directory, that is why you can't find the files you want.

The Wordpress files are located at `/var/www/html`

I see no problem to use the launcher and tweak the codes, the best way to access the server is using sftp as it is more secure.

Comment: Thank you. I can find it now. However, I don't seem to be able to modify those directory. Is it because they are created by the launcher and I am therefore not the owner?

Comment: The directory and files belongs to user "www-data" if you want to modify this files you can do it as superuser, to become superuser you need to ssh the server and type "sudo su" at command line. Before you alter any file remember to make a backup.

Comment: Thank you very much again. I just solved it in another way. I added myself to the group www-data. However, I have got another problem. After modifying and adding some folders into the Wordpress installation, I was made the owner of them. This made Wordpress won't be able to modify them.

Comment: Yep, you can change the ownership with chown www-data:www-data [file]

Answer (score 4):

In the above answers its told that under google cloud, Wordpress `core/website` files are to be found here: `/var/www/html`

But I found my WP files here: `/opt/bitnami/apps/Wordpress/htdocs`. Maybe because I'm using Bitnami Wordpress in GCP. So my answer might help a bitnami WP user.
Also, as told in one of the answers above, I'm not able to change or rename any file there.

I am browsing my Google Cloud Installation through SFTP client FileZilla through Puttykey method. Hope this answer helps someone, who couldn't find WP files in the `/var/www/html` location.

Answer (score 1):

Access your Wordpress file via instance SHH.

Switch to root using command sudo -i

Path for Wordpress file is

> /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/

To edit a file use the command vi "file.name".

Then enter insert mode. Just hit i
To close and save the file, press esc then type :x then the key enter.

Answer (score 0):

Access your Wordpress file via instance SHH.

Switch to root using command sudo -i

Path for Wordpress file is

/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/

To edit a file use the command vi "file.name".

Then enter insert mode. Just hit i To close and save the file, press esc then type :x then the key enter.

*This worked for me aswell.

[https://onepagezen.com/manage-wordpress-files-on-google-cloud-platform/][1]

When searching from googles SSH (which you accessed from the key Putty Generates)